# updates in month and day differences

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, datediff

I have a table as shown below:

[image]

Note: the MAX last_orderdate is 20131015 and the format is yyyymmdd.

I would like to show the final result looks like below:

[image]

Is there any query to help me in this as I have 200000 plus records.

Thank you very much for spending your time to look at my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [**DATEDIFF()**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function

Try this:

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.monthDiff = DATEDIFF(mm, CONVERT(DATE, A.orderDate, 112), B.lastOrderDate), 
    A.dayDiff = DATEDIFF(dd, CONVERT(DATE, A.orderDate, 112), B.lastOrderDate)
FROM tableA A, (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(DATE, orderDate, 112)) lastOrderDate FROM tableA) B
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7f4c/2)

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | ORDERDATE | MONTHDIFF | DAYDIFF |
|----|-----------|-----------|---------|
|  1 |  20130105 |         9 |     283 |
|  2 |  20130205 |         8 |     252 |
|  3 |  20130305 |         7 |     224 |
|  4 |  20130909 |         1 |      36 |
|  5 |  20131001 |         0 |      14 |
|  6 |  20131015 |         0 |       0 |
```

Comment: does this update entire column at once ?? can you tell me the logic i'm new to sql server

Comment: @Saharsh Shah Hi, I use this query, but the result show "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." do you know how to solve this problem? thanks

Comment: @user3094424 Check my updated answer It will work. I forgot that you had stored date in this format `yyyymmdd`. We have to change the format of that date column than we can get the date difference.

Comment: @Saharsh Shah may I know what is 'STR_TO_DATE'?

Comment: @user3094424 Check updated answer. STR_TO_DATE function is used to convert string to date but that is MySQL function. I forgot that you want in SQL Server

Comment: @Saharsh Shah Thanks for taking time to reply my questions, anyway, I have one more question here, what are your 'A' and 'B' mean? Does they mean 2 different tables? But my orderDate and lastOrderDate come from the same table

Comment: @user3094424 You're most welcome... `A` and `B` is the alias of the tables. In my query `A` table means the table in which UPDATE will run and `B` fetches only `lastOrderDate` to compare with `orderDate` of `A`

Comment: @user3094424 If you got desired solution than as an active member on stackoverflow you must have to accept and upvote the answer which will fulfill your requirement. You can accept the answer by clicking on TRUE sign on the left side of question and upvote the answer by clicking on UP ARROW on the left side of question. Take a tour of StackOverflow on http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Saharsh Shah I still cannot run  the query well, it show the result "Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." I think is because my orderdate and lastorderdate is varchar (8), do you have any idea to convert this to the date format? Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3094424 I had converted all the dates in dateformat. Now it must run.

Comment: @user3094424 Check the `SQL FIDDLE DEMO`. It is working on your sample input data.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
declare @a date
set @a='20130105'

declare @b date
set @b='20131015'

select datediff(d,@a,@b) as date_diff,datediff(m,@a,@b) as month_diff
```

Comment: Hi, I have thousand plus records, your query above only can help me do 1 by 1, I need a query to do everything at once and update them? do you have any good suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 

`select DATEDIFF(DAYOFYEAR,'20131015','20131125')`. 

`DAYOFYEAR` represents count of days. Depeneds on your requirement, you can change to see month,day or year difference using  `DATEDIFF`

Comment: Hi, I have thousand plus records, your query above only can help me do 1 by 1, I need a query to do everything at once and update them? do you have any good suggestion?

Comment: CURSOR will help for you. you have 2 columns to see the difference, select those 2 columns in the cursor and update it.